# How to assert whether autowired instance is right class?

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing

My Java project uses Spring. I have an interface `Connector` that's implemented by several classes, `ConnectorV1`, `ConnectorV2`, and so on.

The classes are annotated `@Component("V1")`, `@Component("V2")`, and so on, to distinguish them. The classes are configured for request scope. For example:

```
@Component("V2")
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class ConnectorV2 implements Connector {
```

One of my integration test classes uses `@Autowired @Qualifier("V2")` to obtain an instance of `ConnectorV2` as `classUnderTest` and test it. I lately found that I had accidentally wired the `ConnectorV1` and received weird test results. I'd therefore like to double-check in one of the test methods that I really have the right class at hand.

Unfortunately, all my attempts to assert the concrete class of `classUnderTest` failed because the instance at runtime is first of all a `com.sun.proxy$Proxy{someNumber}`. Even flexible assertions like AssertJ's `assertThat(classUnderTest).isInstanceOf(ConnectorV2.class)` fail to identify the actual class.

Is there a way to look beyond that proxy and see the "real" class that it encapsulates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass(controller)`. Here is a simple example:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Question.ControllerV2.class)
public class Question {

    @Component("V2")
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    static class ControllerV2 implements Controller {}

    interface Controller {}

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("V2")
    private Controller controller;

    @Test
    void testInstanceOf() {
        Class<?> clazz = AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass(controller);
        Assertions.assertThat(clazz).isEqualTo(ControllerV2.class);
    }

}
```

Though, are you sure this is a good idea? This will couple the test to the implementation. The B.D.D. approach suggests testing the behavior and abstracting away the implementation details from the test - making refactoring easier.

Comment: AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass is a clever idea, thanks! Yes, I agree that we should test the behavior. My tests address classes under tests exclusively via interfaces. Unfortunately, the more Spring configuration you have, the more behavior it becomes... So I have to find a compromise between pretending that all these Spring annotations are "no code" and always work and accepting that they are easily misconfigured... I'll reconsider the setup.